# didUpdateLocations called only when app comes to foreground after location is requested while in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm having an iOS application, which has background mode enabled for remote notifications. The `CLLocationManager` instance used throughout is authorized through `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

I have an internal logic to trigger the app upon receiving silent push notifications (`content-available: 1`) from `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, which further calls `requestLocation` on the `CLLocationManager` object.

When the app is in foreground, all works good, and the app receives the location update from iOS within some time of the reception of the silent push.

But, in the case when the app is in background, the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` properly gets triggered and the `requestLocation` is being called. But, I'm not receiving any hit on the `didUpdateLocations` for quite a long time after this. After this, when the app is then again brought back to the foreground, the location update is received through the callback.

So, it looks like the app is waiting to come to foreground to trigger the location update (though it was requested for quite some time ago).

1. What could be the logical reasoning behind this? Or, could this be specific to any device(s) or iOS version(s)?
2. What could be a solution to this issue?

Comment: You should show your code, but you either need to 1) not call the completion handler until you have received the location update or 2) use `beginBackgroundTask` to extend your background run time until you get the location update

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry, but unable to share the code as it is since it involves sensitive information. This is actually **working** on another sample project which was created to test this functionality, but not working on our main project. So I was trying to see what I could have possibly missed.

And, completionHandler is not being called before the update is received.

Comment: @Paulw11 And, I have included all the calls for methods herewith in the question.

Comment: If you can't share the code, then it is going to be difficult to help you.  It is what you are doing *in* `didRecieveRemoteNotification` that is the issue.  Simply telling us the functions you are calling and the delegate methods you have implemented doesn't help.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry for the delayed response. I understand the same. But, I had been running in a situation where spinning a sample application to demonstrate the same was not feasible. But, I did find the root cause of the issue later on. Will probably add it below soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the Background Modes from the capabilities of the project and enable the 'Location updates'. After enabling this, the only configuration to get the updates in the background(not in killed state) is to set'allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' to true(which you have done already).

For more information on getting location in the background follow :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates

Comment: The background mode for Location Updates was obviously the first thing I also went to verify. But that was already enabled.